# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in E:\wamp\www\Demo 22\gallery.php on line 404?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, warnings

I give a image display PHP code in a page while i am not insert images in a database i had occur this error called

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in E:\wamp\www\Demo 22\gallery.php on line 404?

And this is code:

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$select_posts = "select * from album1 where post_id=1";

$run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$select_posts);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){

   $post_title = $row['post_title'];
   $post_name =  $row['post_name'];
   $post_image = $row['post_image'];`enter code here`
?>

<p><?php echo $post_title; ?></p>
<a href="gallery1.php"><img class="gallery1" src="image/album1/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"width="160" height="120" ></a>
<p><?php echo $post_name; ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This means your previous call to `mysqli_query` returned `false` instead of reference to result set. This happens when there is syntax error in the SQL. Try running the SQL manually or report the error by calling `echo mysqli_error($con)`.

Comment: You should have voted to close this as a duplicate instead of answering it.